# Can I use TypeScript's type specialisation with classes?

Tags: typescript

In TS I can do this:

```
type CompleteRecord = {
  complete: true;
  name: string;
  value: number;
};

type PartialRecord = { complete: false } & Partial<CompleteRecord>;

type Record = PartialRecord | CompleteRecord;
```

Now a record can have `complete` set to `true`, in which case I guarantee that all the fields are filled in, or `complete` can be set to `false` and have some fields missing.

Is there a way to do the same thing with a class?  I want to make some of the fields optional only if another field has a specific value.

Edit:

In other words, given a class:

```js
class Record {
  complete: boolean;
  name: string;
  value: number;
};
```

is there a way to have the type of `name` and `value` depend on the value of `complete`?  The type of `name`, for instance, would be something like `complete ? string : (string | undefined)` (I realise that's not valid but it shows the intent of what I'm trying to do).

Comment: for `PartialRecord` you maybe meant `type PartialRecord = { complete: false } & Omit<Partial<CompleteRecord>, 'complete'>;`? Because currently it is `never`.

Comment: "Is there a way to do the same thing with a class?" Please present a [mre] we can play around with.  I'm pretty sure the answer here is going to look like "not really, instances of `class`-declared classes cannot directly be unions", but there might be appropriate alternatives that meet your needs.  But concrete code will help lead to concrete suggestions.

Comment: @jcalz well the problem is that I have no idea how to go about writing this.  I'll have a go at showing what I'd like to do.

Comment: @jcalz ok, done

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJBa6W) using generics work? You can't make a declared class instance a union type but you can make it generic.  If it meets your needs I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - Yes, I rather think it does, thank you.

Comment: I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Hold off for a bit, another idea has come my way.  I'll try to put together a working example.

Comment: Uh, okay, it would have been nice to hear that before I started writing up an answer. That's why I asked the previous comment in the first place, to prevent spending time on something that benefits neither of us.

Comment: Sorry, my kids needed my attention and then I came back to it.  Still happy to mark your answer as correct if you want to finish writing it up as it does answer the question.

Comment: Eh, kind of takes the wind out of my sails. I'm switching to another task for a bit, and if there's something new or different when I come back I'll take another look.

Comment: I think [this](https://tsplay.dev/mALeRN) gets me 99% of what I was missing though; a type guard in the class was most of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` polymorphism, you can make the type of `complete` depend on the type of the other fields:

```
class Entry {
  complete
    : false | (undefined extends this["name"] | this["value"] ? never : true)
    = false;
  name?: string ;
  value?: number;
};
```

It's not as easy to use in this state, compared to the other types in the question:

```
const a = new Entry();
a.complete = true; // error: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.

const b = Object.assign(a, {name: "a", value: 4})
b.complete = true; // OK
```

But since were making this into a class, we probably want to use methods instead:

```
  setName(newName: string): asserts this is {name:string} {
    this.name = newName;
  }

  setValue(newValue: number): asserts this is {value: number} {
    this.value = newValue;
  }
```

```
const c: Entry = new Entry();
c.complete = true; // error: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'
c.setValue(1);
c.setName("g");
c.complete = true; // OK
```